# flutter channel master error Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches

Tags: flutter, dart

i try to change a flutter channel from stable to master but i got this error when i want to change it:

```
git: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
git:    packages/flutter/lib/src/material/elevated_button.dart
git: Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
git: Aborting
Switching channels failed with error code 1.
```

I used this flutter upgrade --force but not worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cd` into your Flutter SDK directory and run `git restore .`. This should remove any changes you have made to the source code on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, you have some changes that you manually did in `elevated_button.dart`. You need to git rid of those changes from the file path mentioned in the error and then try again.